# how do you implement a delayed object constructor in clojure?

Tags: clojure

this is motivated by the 'art of the propagator' paper by Radul and Sussman at:

http://web.mit.edu/~axch/www/art.pdf

when they are building a `compound progator`, they say:

> a compound propagator is implemented with a procedure that will construct the propagator’s body on demand. We take care that it is constructed only if some neighbor actually has a value, and that it is constructed only once

the code on page 10 is:

```
(define (compound-propagator neighbors to-build)
  (let ((done? #f) (neighbors (listify neighbors)))
    (define (test)
      (if done?
          ’ok
        (if (every nothing? (map content neighbors))
            ’ok
          (begin (set! done? #t)
                 (to-build)))))
    (propagator neighbors test)))
```

How do we do this using clojure's persistent data structures?

---

a simplified version of this maybe:

```
(def m {:a (delayed (some-object-constructor))})
```

where `(:a m)` constructs the object on the first call and gives 
and then subsequent calls to `(:a m)` will access the object.

its sort of like memoize but on values rather than functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as delayed execution, [delay](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/delay) might be a place to start. It could be used to evaluate the constructor only on the first dereference. It might look something like this:

```
(defn some-object-constructor
  []
  (println "Making something!")
  :something)

(def m {:a (delay (some-object-constructor))})

(println "Doing some intermediate work.")

(println (deref (:a m)))
```